# Outputting Strings in Android

Tags: android

I am new to Android development and am kind of stuck with something I am trying to do.
I have an app where users have to pick a date, enter in a string in an edittext box and then make a choice from a spinner.
At the bottom of the screen, I would like to have a button that displays the results of all three of these in a toast.
My first question is if this is even possible? Can I put a listener for an edittext, a text box and a spinner all on the same button.
Is it possible to export the user's responses to string files that I can then use the button to call up.
I hope this makes sense and that someone can help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This kind of confusion is not uncommon at the beginning. I don't understand the cause of the down vote.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. 
You have to use a `onClickListener` on the `Button`

Get the value of selected spinner item:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
String text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Get the value of edittext input:

```
String input = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_something)).getText().toString();
```

Get the value of datepicker input:

```
DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.datepicker);
int   day  = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
int   month= datePicker.getMonth();
int   year = datePicker.getYear();

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String formattedDate = sdf.format(new Date(year, month, day));
```

Create the toast:

```
String toastText = text + input + formattedDate;
Toast.makeText(this,toastText,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can I put a listener for an edittext, a text box and a spinner all on the same button?

No. You can register a listener to a view for that particular view (edittext, button, text box all are views). So for the button you will register a listener with it for that particular button's event. When the button is clicked, you will collect the text from the edittext, text box etc. and make a `Toast`.

> ```
> Is it possible to export the user's responses to string files that I can then use the button to call up?
> ```

Yes it is possible. You can store the inputs from the user into a file and show them when the button is pressed. But it is really an unnecessary process unless you want to learn how to read/write files.